# cakePHP Using authenticate.multicolumn plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to use [this plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/Authenticate/blob/master/Controller/Component/Auth/MultiColumnAuthenticate.php) which looks pretty easy to use, but I just dont understand one thing, even after going through the little documentation they provide..
I tried this in my appController :

```
function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Authenticate.MultiColumn' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'login',
                'password' => 'password'
            ),
            'columns' => array('username', 'barcode_auth'),
            'userModel' => 'User',
            'scope' => array('User.active' => 1)
        )
    );
}
```

Where username needs to check for username or barcode_aut (which is barcode entry).. 
What I am not sure of is the setup for the  `fields` key.. As it suggests, the keys `username` and `password` represent the input fields. But what is expected ? Field ID's? and what about the values `login` and `password`? what do they represent? Is it the user input?

Any help regarding this is appreciated !! thanks in advance

**[EDIT]**

The result of the current result is simply a redirection to the same page..

Comment: fields key is to recognize the form input names, so with your code you would have inputs for login and password. The login field can accept username or barcode_auth

Comment: Thanks for you comment! I got this working. The problem was that I had  the value for the 'username' field as login, but it should have been 'username'! thanks